evolution mail: save sender public S/MIME certificate
I'm using Evolution 3.52.3 on Noble and I've noticed that when I get a S/MIME signed mail, is no more possible to import sender's public certificate.
I've done a test on Evolution 3.18.5 on an old Xenial I still have in an old pc and there I can export sender certificate (view certificate, then right click on top-right icon and choose "export certificate", finally import it in contact).
The same happens with evolution 3.28.5 on Bionic, with 3.36.1 on Focal and 3.44.4 on Jammy, so it seems that is a problem (or a bug) related to 3.52.3 version.
Can someone suggest me how to resolve this problem?
Thanks
